# Django - Class Based View for a specific item

Tags: django, django-views

Building a Django app where I have a view that displays a list of distinct case.  When you click on a case, I'd like it to take you to a list of items related to the case (in this case it's a list of devices).  The issue I am facing I don't know how to make the view display only the items related to that case (right now it displays every item in every case).

Views:

```
class MdeListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Mde
    template_name = 'mde/mde.html'
    ordering = [F('date').desc()]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Mde.objects.distinct('case_number')


class MdeCaseListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Mde
    template_name = 'mde/mde_case_list.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import MdeListView, MdeCreateView, MdeCaseListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/list', MdeCaseListView.as_view(), name='mde_case_list'),
    path('new', MdeCreateView.as_view(), name='mde_new'),
    path('', MdeListView.as_view(), name='mde'),
]
```

The url goes to the right record based on the primary key, but from there I want only the items that use the same case_number as that primary key.

Comment: Apparently you put `get_queryset` function in the wrong class, you need to put it in `MdeCaseListView` class.

Comment: You would be correct, but was using a get_queryset in that one as well.  Thanks for looking thought!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out!

```
class MdeCaseListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Mde
    template_name = 'mde/mde_case_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        pkey = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        case = Mde.objects.filter(id=pkey).values_list('case_number', flat=True)
        return Mde.objects.filter(case_number=case[0])
```